# Website timeout, but only on mobile devices - IIS

Tags: iis, networking

I am trying to test a website on mobile devices, but I keep getting timeouts on Android (using Chrome) and iOS tablets and smartphones (using Safari).  My Windows tablet and a separate Windows PC (both using Chrome) work fine. Here is my network setup.  It's a little convoluted, but blame COVID-19 and working remotely for that.
**Web Application:** DotNetNuke running on IIS using dedicated MSSQL database to store user account information and localization settings.

**Web Server:** Windows 10 running a local MSSQL web server database and IIS. Connected Wireless to my internal network.  Using a VPN client to connect to the Rest API within my work network to access the core application server. The web server has a self-signed, untrusted certificate.

**Windows PC:** Windows 10 laptop connected via wire to the network. Certificate error is ignored by the user in Chrome and the webpage comes up.

**Windows Tablet:** HP tablet running Windows 10 connected wireless to my network. Certificate error is ignored by the user in Chrome and the webpage comes up.

**Android Phone:** Google Pixel 3 connected via WiFi to my network. Using Chrome, connection times out.

I've try a couple of Android devices and an iPhone, and neither connect.  I'm not sure where to begin debugging this. I know it worked last week because I tested the configuration to prepare for testing this week. Any blaring issues to look at, other than perhaps a code change that broke the mobile rendering?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I got the same issue, but only when connecting to http. Https works fine for me. Even using the rewrite rule to redirect http to https does not work.

Comment: No, and unfortunately I moved on to another project in the interim.

Answer (score 0):

What is the way of your Windows Tablet connected the network? Is the wireless connected way the same to Android Phone?  in other words, using WiFi too?
I doubt if your Wifi network works like before. Check your IP of the Android Phone, then Ping the IP on the webserver, and confirm whether the network with the target web server is unobstructed.
Alternatively, we Ping the gateway of the network on both an Android phone and the website.
About the Ping Tool in Android phone.
https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/android-networking-apps/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: It seems all non-Windows devices timeout. The Windows tablet is only connected via wifi.  I used my wife's Mac to test, and it also timed out. I'm leaning to my web server's network settings; is there something that would prevent non-Windows devices from connecting?  I'm going to try connecting to the PC through my file explorer on the Google Pixel later today to see what results I get.

Comment: Try the Ping Tool the check the network connectivity.
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/ping-a-computer-using-network-utility-on-mac-mchlp1003/mac